# Recursively execute funcs in list

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, functional-programming

Given a list of `Func<string, string>`, is it possible to write a statement that iterates through the list and returns the result like so:

```
string result = f1(f2(f..(input));
```

I have the following code (that works), but I'm not satisfied with the temporary variable.

```
public static string WrapEachElementWith<T>
    (   this IEnumerable<T> target, 
        params Func<string, string>[] func )
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    target.Each(s =>
                    {
                        var tmp = s.ToString();
                        func.Reverse().Each(x => tmp = x(tmp));
                        result += tmp;
                    });
    return result;
}
```

How to simplify / refactor?

UPDATE:
I should have provided more background. I'm playing around with Functional programming in c# after seeing higher order JavaScript session and John's abusive c# session at Oredev.

The aim is to generate html.

```
var TABLE = WrapWith("TABLE");
var TR = WrapWith("TR");
var TD = WrapWith("TD");
const string expected = "<TABLE><TR><TD>1</TD></TR><TR><TD>2</TD></TR></TABLE>";

var result = TABLE(stringArray.WrapEachWith(TR, TD));
result.ShouldEqual(expected);

static Func<String, String> WrapWith(string element)
{
    var startTag = '<' + element + '>';
    var endTag = "</" + element + '>';
    return s => startTag + s + endTag;
}
```

Comment: Recursion? Something like `applyMany s [] = s`; `applyMany s (f:fs) = applyMany (f s) fs` in C#?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's your reasoning behind using recursion for this?

Comment: see update in my question, I'm trying to wrap elements in HTML using a list of elements I want to wrap it with

Comment: I made a mistake in the question update, it now has valid code.

Comment: You don't generate HTML this way. Just like you don't parse XML by hand, let alone with regexes. The problem is much too complex and already solved for you to mess with it manually.

Comment: Delnan, this is not about solving anything; it's about an exercise. However, I would like to know how it has been solved before (as an aside). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you're doing four things:

- Converting each item to a string
- Applying the functions in turn
- Applying that composite function to each string in a sequence
- Joining the results together (inefficiently)

I would separate out those four aspects - in particular, `string.Join` works well enough for the fourth part, and `Enumerable.Select` does the third one.

I would also avoid reversing the order of the operations - I would expect the first operation I specify to be the first one applied, personally.

So, I would rewrite this method to *return* a `Func<string, string>` which could then be used with `Select` and `Join`. For example:

```
public static Func<string, string> Compose(params Func<string, string> funcs)
{
    return input => {
        string current = input;
        foreach (var func in funcs)
        {
            current = func(current);
        }
        return current;
    };
}
```

You could, of course, make this generic itself, with a signature of:

```
public static Func<T, T> Compose(params Func<T, T> funcs)
```

You would then call it with something like:

```
var composite = Compose<string>(FirstFunction, SecondFunction, ThirdFunction);

var query = string.Join("", items.Select(x => x.ToString())
                                 .Select(composite));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string WrapEachElementWith
    (   string input, 
        params Func<string, string>[] func )
{
    foreach (var f in func.Reverse())
        input = f(input);
    return input;
}
```

Not sure why you need template parameter, all the functions map string to string, right?

Note that there's no `Each` extension of `IEnumerable`, so you'll have to resort to `foreach` or write your own `Each`.

Edit:
your code actually applies this function to all the values from the list, so the actual code would be something like:

```
public static string F<T>
    (   this IEnumerable<T> target, 
        params Func<string, string>[] func )
{
    target.Select(item => WrapEachElementWith(item.ToString(), func))
          .Aggregate((sum, cur) => sum + cur);
}
```

As @Jon already mentioned, summing up this way is pretty inefficient, therefore you perhaps would like to put it this way:

```
string.Join("", target.Select(
                  item => WrapEachElementWith(item.ToString(), func)));
```

Comment: Each input is T, and ToString is called once to start with.

Comment: @Jon: I assumed it's called one per `target`'s item.

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lukeh/taking-linq-to-objects-to-extremes-a-fully-linqified-raytracer) wrote an entire ray tracer using LINQ. I haven't looked at his code that closely, but he describes using a technique called a "Y-combinator" to create recursion in a LINQ statement. He references [this blog posting](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310134116/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx), which gives a detailed description of these recursive lambda expressions.

I don't know if that's quite what you're looking for, but it might get you off on the right footing.